# Change baud rate of ESP8266

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266

I update my esp8266-1 firmware sdk 1.5.0 AT version:0.51.0.0(Nov 27 2015 13:37:21).

Now I cant change my baud rate to 9600.

I tried AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0 and AT+UART=9600,8,1,0,0 to change my baud rate. But after power off baud rate change to 115200. What can i do to save my default baud rate?